# How do I get a count of fields in a column eliminating duplicate entries in that field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to get a count on total invoices for each customer.  The table I'm pulling the information from is a transactional table that may have numerous entries for each invoice number([Document No_]).  The result of this query is giving me a count of lines for each customer but not a distinct count of invoices.  I'm Not sure how to write this.

```
SELECT top 20  a.[Sell-to Customer No_], 
               b.[Name], 
               sum(a.[Amount])as 'Total Sales Amount', 
               avg(a.Amount) as 'Average per Purchase', 
               count(a.[Document No_]) as 'Total Invoices'
FROM [Sales Invoice Line] a left outer join [Customer] b
ON a.[Sell-to Customer No_] = b.[No_]
WHERE [Posting Group] like 'PAR'
and a.[Shipment Date] >= '10-01-2013' 
GROUP BY a.[Sell-to Customer No_], b.[Name]
```

Comment: What database is this? Does it support `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`?

Comment: `count(distinct a.[Document No_]) as 'Total Invoices'`

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management studio(dont laugh) 2005.

Comment: I was adding select preceding distinct.  Just tried it using distinct only.  Works perfectly...Thank you.

Comment: @CraigZirnheld I won't laugh!  You were very close to the correct answer (only 1 word off) and I upgraded from VS 2005 in the last year.

Comment: I was writing subs and everything else.  Been writing SQL for about 6 months and have learned exponentially.  I have found the answer is usually much simpler than I try to make it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
count(distinct...)
```

instead of

```
count(...)
```